# Perl Queue and Threads abnormal exit

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am quite new to Perl, especially Perl Threads.
I want to accomplish:

1. Have 5 threads that will en-queue data(Random numbers) into a
   Thread::queue
2. Have 3 threads that will de-queue data from the
   Thread::queue.

The complete code that I wrote in order to achieve above mission:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;


my $queue = new Thread::Queue();
our @Enquing_threads;
our @Dequeuing_threads;

sub buildQueue
{
    my $TotalEntry=1000;
    while($TotalEntry-- >0)
    {
        my $query = rand(10000);
        $queue->enqueue($query);
        print "Enque thread with TID " .threads->tid . " got $query,";
        print "Queue Size: " . $queue->pending . "\n";
    }
}
sub process_Queue 
{
    my $query;
    while ($query = $queue->dequeue) 
    {
        print "Dequeu thread with TID " .threads->tid . " got $query\n";
    }
}
push @Enquing_threads,threads->create(\&buildQueue) for 1..5;
push @Dequeuing_threads,threads->create(\&process_Queue) for 1..3;
```

**Issues that I am Facing**:

- The threads are not running as  concurrently as expected.
- The entire program abnormally exit with following  console output:

> Perl exited with active threads:
>           8 running and unjoined
>
> ```
>     0 finished and unjoined
>     0 running and detached
>
>     Enque thread with TID 5 got 6646.13585023883,Queue Size: 595 
>     Enque thread with TID 1 got 3573.84104215917,Queue Size: 595
> ```

Any help on code-optimization is appreciated.

Comment: Why did you use `our` instead of `my`? You should never have to use `our` except when forced (`@ISA`, `@EXPORT`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is to be expected: When the main thread exits, all other threads exit as well. If you don't care, you can `$thread->detach` them. Otherwise, you have to manually `$thread->join` them, which we'll do.

The `$thread->join` waits for the thread to complete, and fetches the return value (threads can return values just like subroutines, although the context (list/void/scalar) has to be fixed at spawn time).

We will `detach` the threads that enqueue data:

```
threads->create(\&buildQueue)->detach for 1..5;
```

Now for the dequeueing threads, we put them into a *lexical variable* (why are you using globals?), so that we can dequeue them later:

```
my @dequeue_threads = map threads->create(\&process_queue), 1 .. 3;
```

Then wait for them to complete:

```
$_->join for @dequeue_threads;
```

We know that the detached threads will finish execution before the programm exits, because the only way for the dequeueing threads to exit is to exhaust the queue.

Except for one and a half bugs. You see, there is a difference between an empty queue and a finished queue. If the queue is just empty, the dequeueing threads will block on `$queue->dequeue` until they get some input. The traditional solution is to `dequeue` while the value they get is defined. We can break the loop by supplying as many `undef` values in the queue as there are threads reading from the queue. More modern version of `Thread::Queue` have an `end` method, that makes `dequeue` return `undef` for all subsequent calls.

The problem is *when* to end the queue. We should to this after all enqueueing threads have exited. Which means, we should wait for them manually. Sigh.

```
my @enqueueing = map threads->create(\&enqueue), 1..5;
my @dequeueing = map threads->create(\&dequeue), 1..3;
$_->join for @enqueueing;
$queue->enqueue(undef) for 1..3;
$_->join for @dequeueing;
```

And in `sub dequeuing`: `while(defined( my $item = $queue->dequeue )) { ... }`.

Using the `defined` test fixes another bug: `rand` can return zero, although this is quite unlikely and will slip through most tests. The contract of `rand` is that it returns a pseudo-random floating point number between including zero and excluding some upper bound: A number from the interval `[0, x)`. The bound defaults to `1`.

If you don't want to join the enqueueing threads manually, you could use a semaphore to signal completition. A semaphore is a multithreading primitive that can be incremented and decremented, but not below zero. If a decrement operation would let the drop count below zero, the call blocks until another thread raises the count. If the start count is `1`, this can be used as a flag to block resources.

We can also start with a negative value `1 - $NUM_THREADS`, and have each thread increment the value, so that only when all threads have exited, it can be decremented again.

```
use threads;  # make a habit of importing `threads` as the first thing

use strict; use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Thread::Queue;
use Thread::Semaphore;

use constant {
  NUM_ENQUEUE_THREADS => 5,  # it's good to fix the thread counts early
  NUM_DEQUEUE_THREADS => 3,
};

sub enqueue {
  my ($out_queue, $finished_semaphore) = @_;
  my $tid = threads->tid;

  # iterate over ranges instead of using the while($maxval --> 0) idiom
  for (1 .. 1000) {
    $out_queue->enqueue(my $val = rand 10_000);
    say "Thread $tid enqueued $val";
  }

  $finished_semaphore->up;
  # try a non-blocking decrement. Returns true only for the last thread exiting.
  if ($finished_semaphore->down_nb) {
    $out_queue->end;  # for sufficiently modern versions of Thread::Queue
    # $out_queue->enqueue(undef) for 1 .. NUM_DEQUEUE_THREADS;
  }
}

sub dequeue {
  my ($in_queue) = @_;
  my $tid = threads->tid;
  while(defined( my $item = $in_queue->dequeue )) {
    say "thread $tid dequeued $item";
  }
}

# create the queue and the semaphore
my $queue = Thread::Queue->new;
my $enqueuers_ended_semaphore = Thread::Semaphore->new(1 - NUM_ENQUEUE_THREADS);

# kick off the enqueueing threads -- they handle themself
threads->create(\&enqueue, $queue, $enqueuers_ended_semaphore)->detach for 1..NUM_ENQUEUE_THREADS;

# start and join the dequeuing threads
my @dequeuers = map threads->create(\&dequeue, $queue), 1 .. NUM_DEQUEUE_THREADS;
$_->join for @dequeuers;
```

Don't be suprised if the threads do not seem to run in parallel, but sequentially: This task (enqueuing a random number) is very fast, and is not well suited for multithreading (enqueueing is more expensive than creating a random number).

Here is a sample run where each enqueuer only creates two values:

```
Thread 1 enqueued 6.39390993005694
Thread 1 enqueued 0.337993319585337
Thread 2 enqueued 4.34504733960242
Thread 2 enqueued 2.89158054485114
Thread 3 enqueued 9.4947585773571
Thread 3 enqueued 3.17079715055542
Thread 4 enqueued 8.86408863197179
Thread 5 enqueued 5.13654995317669
Thread 5 enqueued 4.2210886147538
Thread 4 enqueued 6.94064174636395
thread 6 dequeued 6.39390993005694
thread 6 dequeued 0.337993319585337
thread 6 dequeued 4.34504733960242
thread 6 dequeued 2.89158054485114
thread 6 dequeued 9.4947585773571
thread 6 dequeued 3.17079715055542
thread 6 dequeued 8.86408863197179
thread 6 dequeued 5.13654995317669
thread 6 dequeued 4.2210886147538
thread 6 dequeued 6.94064174636395
```

You can see that `5` managed to enqueue a few things before `4`. The threads `7` and `8` don't get to dequeue anything, `6` is too fast. Also, all enqueuers are finished before the dequeuers are spawned (for such a small number of inputs).

Comment: @amon: One more thing, what 3 building(enquing) and 5 dequeing(processing) threads, comes under what type of thread model? Is it, Boss-Worker thread model?

Comment: @ritesh_NITW In a *boss-worker* model, one thread distributes the load across multiple worker threads (often from a thread pool). Our program doesn't fit this description too well. I'd rather describe this as a *producer-consumer* or *pipeline* architecture.

Comment: @amon: The program still did n't exit. However, I can see thread 8 dequeued 1000. 
I am getting an error msg :'Thread 5 terminated abnormally: Can't locate object method "down_nb" via package "Thread::Semaphore" at test.pl line 27.'
Perl Version that I am using ** perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi**

Comment: @ritesh_NITW It seems you'd need at least v2.11 of Thread::Semaphore for the `down_nb` method. You can get your version by `perl -MThread::Semaphore -le'print $Thread::Semaphore::VERSION'`. You could install a newer version from CPAN. Note that `say` is only available since perl 5.10. I didn't target earlier perls (and strongly suggest upgrading to a [supported version](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpolicy.html#MAINTENANCE-AND-SUPPORT) for bugfixes and new features). I tested under perl 5.18.1.